# Can someone explain what this codes does?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap my head around what this codes snippet does, but I don't seem to get it.

```js
var sentence = ' u i am a girl ';
   
    for(var i = 0; i<sentence.length;i++){
        if (sentence.charAt(i) != ' '){
            sentence = sentence.substring(i, sentence.length);
            console.log(sentence.substring(i, sentence.length));
        
            break
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Question is not self-explanatory.

Comment: I would suggest writing it out on paper - follow the execution of the code and write down any variable values. I find this really helps break down the issue into manageable portions...
As it currently stands, this question is not really a good fit for [so] I'm afraid.

Comment: Just run the code and see it by yourself.

Comment: @sjahan - thats not a very helpful comment at all. It's actually rather rude.

Comment: Is there any specific part of the code that you're struggling with, @OdunayoO? Or is it more an issue of being able to follow the execution?

Comment: @Lix It's not really rude, I would actually run it and test it on several sentences to see what it does.

Comment: @sjahan - Someone posts a question and your response is - "find it out by yourself" - this is not a welcoming tone and it does not help any sides involved.

Comment: @Lix On that kind of basics, I honestly think the best way to learn is to get it by yourself and not asking for help too early, otherwise, you do not make the effort to get it and memorize it. It's not that much of a work on that piece of code, and if you do not make effort on that kind of code, how can you expect to progress? No offense was meant at all.

Comment: @sjahan - I'm sure you didn't mean any harm by it - however we need to remember that users on the site are in different places in their careers and what might seem trivial to one dev will not be so obvious to another. Without knowing the level of expertise of the person you're trying to help, you need to be aware of the fact that our "advice"  can very easily come off as condescending, dismissive, and even rude or mean.

Comment: @OdunayoO - something that was mentioned by others is that there are "better" ways to do the same thing that this code is doing. I think a better question to ask here is not "what this codes does?" but rather "what does this code *want* to do?". It might be trimming whitespace, or removing other characters - once you know what the intention is it'll help a LOT figuring out how the code tried to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var sentence = ' u i am a girl ';
    
    // Loop through the sentence string
    for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
        
        // If the current character isn't one space
        if (sentence.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            
            // Remove all the characters up until the first none-space character
            sentence = sentence.substring(i, sentence.length);
            // Will give us 'u i am a girl '
            
            // Double the amount of removed characters in the remaining string before we log it
            console.log(sentence.substring(i, sentence.length));
            // Since we removed 1 character in the substring before,
            // we will now remove 1 more character 
            // Result will be ' i am a girl '

            // Exit the for loop
            break;
        }

    }
```

It feels like the second substring is unwanted and should be
`console.log(sentence)`, but since I don't know what the code should do I can only explain what it does right now.

Comment: I had the same thoughts - that the console log was supposed to just be logging the string after calling `substring`... but you're right - we can only assume :) Probably copy pasted just to see what the output would be

Comment: *"If the current character is not a whitespace"* is incorrect. whitespace != space, whitespace includes linefeeds, tabs, carriage returns, nonbreaking spaces, etc. That code is looking, specifically, for a space. *"...the first none whitespace..."* I think you meant *"...the first non-space"*. Hesitated to edit.